# Can not save info to database column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm adding a photo posting function with Ruby(Ruby on Rails) and implementing it so that you can post comments from the detail screen (showAction).
but when you write a comment and click the "Post" button, there is no change the screen and the characters that you tried to post in the column are not saved.

COMMENT CONTROLLER

```
class CatPostCommentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.create(cat_comment_params)
    if @cat_post_comment.save
      render "/cat_main/#{cat_post_comment.cat_post.id}"
    end
  end

  private
  def cat_comment_params
    params.require(:cat_post).permit(:cat_post_comment).merge(user_id: current_user.id, cat_post_id: params[:cat_post_id])
  end
end
```

COMMENT MODEL

```
class CatPostComment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :cat_post

  validates :cat_post_comment, presence: true
end
```

VIEW FILE (SHOW ACTION)

```
  <div class="container">
      <%= form_with(model: [@cat_post_comment,@cat_post], url:cat_main_cat_post_comments_path(@cat_post), method: :post, local: true) do |form| %>
        <%= form.text_area :cat_post_comment, placeholder: "add your comments" %>
       <div class="comment_btn"><%= form.submit "subimit" %></div>
      <% end %>
  </div>
```

there is no error message on browser and checked the terminal and found out the error below.

```
Started POST "/cat_main/5/cat_post_comments" for ::1 at 2020-08-20 22:35:20 +0900
Processing by CatPostCommentsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"DgF8MsAPQAqJQzw9GtUoRg5EL+3xWnd9+QZbmGDpo44v4UyauD16C/mKdXhdwP/bSAMmt30ncBV7+/GlDbxlPg==", "cat_post"=>{"cat_post_comment"=>"test\r\n"}, "commit"=>"submit", "cat_main_id"=>"5"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ app/controllers/cat_post_comments_controller.rb:4:in `create'
No template found for CatPostCommentsController#create, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms | Allocations: 7721)
```

but I didn't get what the error comes from, so changed the render path randomly　but didn't work.
Then tried binding.pry and figured out the problem was

```
    3: def create
    4:   @cat_post_comment = CatPostComment.create(cat_comment_params)
 => 5:   binding.pry
    6:   if @cat_post_comment.save
    7:     render "/cat_main/#{cat_post_comment.cat_post.id}"
    8:   end
    9: end

[1] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment
=> #<CatPostComment:0x00007fc6ba1fe540 id: nil, user_id: 1, cat_post_id: nil, cat_post_comment: "テスト", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[2] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: 
Validation failed: please enter Cat post.
from /Users/ayumiuchimura/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-6.0.3.2/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error'
[3] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment.errors.full_messages
=> ["please enter Cat post."]
[4] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)> @cat_post_comment
=> #<CatPostComment:0x00007fc6ba1fe540 id: nil, user_id: 1, cat_post_id: nil, cat_post_comment: "テスト", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
[5] pry(#<CatPostCommentsController>)>
```

The cause is database can not get cat_post_id and the terminal says its nil.
I tried to change description of id like "params:cat_post_ids => []" or put it to permit but did't work any.
That would be great if someone know how to fix it.
I'm looking forward to get some responses, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your params in the request don't have `cat_post_id` but it's have `cat_main_id` instead, so you cannot save the `cat_post_comment` because it missing `cat_post_id`, So check if `cat_main_id` can replace `cat_post_id` your check your form in view

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I didn't even notice the id was wrong and check the controller name and the other files as well. and then, changed the name to cat_post and fixed it!
thank you very much!! it's really helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be `render "/cat_main/#{cat_post.cat_post_comment.id}"` because your cat_post_comment belongs to cat_post and not the other way arround.

**edit**
Looking at your code again I think it should just be `render "/cat_main/#{cat_post_comment.id}"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
There was a problem render path as well like you said so, I changed to {@cat_post_comment.cat_post.id} then saved comment to column!!
thank you sooo much！it's  really helpful!!